# AS3: No hittest detection after a certain amount of movieclips in an array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, loops, for-loop

I realise the description is a bit vague, I couldn't explain the issue without showing the code!

Basically I have made a game in AS3 which incorporates a character moving around a platform style level collecting items. The items are all seperate movieclips of the same instance (vinyl1a).

References to each item in the level are stored in an array as shown:

```
vinylArray=[mapbg.misc.vinyl1, mapbg.misc.vinyl2, mapbg.misc.vinyl3, mapbg.misc.vinyl4,...]
```

The actual array goes up to 40 items. Collision detection is done through a for loop as shown here:

```
var i:int;
for (i=0; i < maxVinyl; i++){ //iterate from 0 to maximum amount of vinyl
    if (woody.hitTestObject(vinylArray[i])) { //checks if woody collides with vinyl
        if (vinylArray[i].visible == true) { //checks if the vinyl has already been taken
        vinylArray[i].visible = false; //removes vinyl from map
        vinylCollected++; //adds to score
        updateScore();
        }
        }
    }
```

In this scenario 'woody' is the character. Now, the issue is, I have had it working perfectly fine for up to 10 'vinyl' items, which covers the first 3 levels of the game. Now I have progressed into the 4th level and I have added more 'vinyl' movieclips to the map (the array has always had 40 values but the for loop only iterates up to 'maxVinyl' which is set for each individual level) and for some reason the collision detection just isn't working.

There are no error messages, and the first 10 movieclips are still detected correctly, but 11 onwards isn't.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - and if you need more information on the problem please ask!

Cheers

EDIT: Forgot to mention, I tested more than 10 vinyl on the first level and the detection works - the situation is that all of the vinyl movieclips are stored in seperate key frames for each level, within a movieclip called misc. So I can do 10+ on the first level but that seems to be it..

Comment: Try adding more in the first couple levels to see if you can get more than 10 there where things seem to be working - that way you can narrow down where the problem is happening.  Also, it would be much more efficient to pop the vinyl items out of the hit test array once you find them instead of checking on all of them every time.  And if you have different levels, only init the vinyl array with the items for that level to further simplify.

Comment: Wow - sorry totally forgot to mention the fact that I tested an extra vinyl on the first level and it detected fine, which makes the problem even more confusing to me! The vinyl movieclips are all stored on seperate keyframes of a movieclip called 'misc' for each level.

Comment: What else is different in level 4?

Comment: Okay sorta thanks to your comment I actually solved the issue myself! Basically I had to put the extra vinyl objects into every level before the one in question and it works fine! Cheers for the response anyway mate!

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine what is happening is that maxVinyl is not set to the correctly length of the array.

A simple :

```
maxVinyl = vinylArray.length;
```

BEFORE the for loop should ensure that all objects in that array are hitTest as desired.

Based on some of the comments, it sounds like there are some other issues with your approach that might be the larger issue.